# How can I count multiple rows for same item?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    IQ.[Item Number], 
    IQ.[Item Description],
    IQ.[QTY On Hand], 
    IQ.[QTY Allocated], 
    IQ.[QTY Available], 
    IQ.[QTY Sold],
    IQ.[Item Class Code] AS [Item Class],
    IQ.[User Category Value 2] AS [License],
    IQ.[Bin Number],
    PL.[QTY Ordered]-[QTY Matched]-[QTY Canceled] AS [PRODUCTION OVERSEAS] -- how can ISNULL be applied here? This returns qty open, also need qty ordered reference column IN PROD OVERSEAS column,
FROM
    [Purchase] PL,
    ItemQuantities IQ
JOIN 
    Purchase ON IQ.[Item Number] = PL.[Item Number]
             AND [Document Date] > DATEADD(Day, -270, GETDATE())
             AND [PO Line Status] NOT IN ('Canceled', 'Closed')
```

[image]

Spreadsheet is showing multiple rows with same item, instead of adding all rows and giving result per item. Grouping by item number only multiplies the quantity.

Comment: Where is the Spreadsheet  ? and please provide sample data and expected output to make it ease to understand.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should **most definitely** not mix the comma-separated `FROM` joins with **proper** ANSI JOINs in a single query..... go for the proper ANSI JOINs - always!

Comment: Thanks for editing. You're awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is a 1:Many relationship between ItemQuantity and Purchase, you will probably want to group by all the columns in the ItemQuantity table in your query. This will necessitate aggregating any other fields. Something like this:

```
SELECT  IQ.[Item Number], 
        IQ.[Item Description],
        IQ.[QTY On Hand] , 
        IQ.[QTY Allocated], 
        IQ.[QTY Available], 
        IQ.[QTY Sold],
        IQ.[Item Class Code] AS [Item Class],
        IQ.[User Category Value 2] AS [License],
        IQ.[Bin Number],
        SUM(ISNULL(PL.[QTY Ordered],0)-ISNULL([QTY Matched],0)-ISNULL([QTY Canceled],0)) AS [PRODUCTION OVERSEAS] 
FROM    [Purchase] PL
        JOIN ItemQuantities IQ ON IQ.[Item Number]=PL.[Item Number]
WHERE   [Document Date] >DATEADD(Day,-270,GETDATE())
        AND [PO Line Status] NOT IN ('Canceled', 'Closed')
GROUP BY IQ.[Item Number], 
        IQ.[Item Description],
        IQ.[QTY On Hand] , 
        IQ.[QTY Allocated], 
        IQ.[QTY Available], 
        IQ.[QTY Sold],
        IQ.[Item Class Code],
        IQ.[User Category Value 2],
        IQ.[Bin Number]
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help, I am still getting // Wrong Syntax near 'ISNULL'

Comment: @AbsAguila, add a comma after `IQ.[Bin Number]` in the `SELECT` list, and don't copy and paste code from the internet into your environment until you've proof-read it and  understand what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.